Pauli-Villars ghosts in the bosonic string theory and critical dimensions
I am a bit confused about the relation between Pauli-Villars ghosts and the need for Faddeev-Popov ghosts in the bosonic string when performing canonical quantisation.
The first encounter with quantising strings in textbooks is to start with the Polyakov action (ignoring numerical constants)
$$S = \int d^2 \sigma h^{ab}\partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} $$
where $\eta = \text{diag}(-1,1,...,1)$.
Then use $diff \times Weyl$ invariance to go to the lightcone gauge, obtaining the action of $d$ free bosons with an $\mathfrak{so}(1,d-1)$ target space Lorentz symmetry.
$$S = \int d \sigma^+d\sigma^- \partial_+ X^\mu \partial_- X^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} .$$
From the equations of motion one then has the separation into left-handed and right-handed coordinates $X^\mu = X_+^\mu(\sigma^+)+X_-^\mu(\sigma^-)$, and one goes through the usual oscillator construction to get the Fock space by expanding the coordinates in Fourier modes
$$ X^\mu_\pm \sim \sum_{n\in\mathbb{z}} \alpha_m^\mu e^{2\pi i \sigma^\pm}. $$
The details (irrelevant here) depending on the open versus closed sectors. The oscillators $\alpha^\mu_m$ satisfy the usual canonical commutation relations
$$[\alpha_m^\mu,\alpha_n^\mu] = m\delta_{m+n,0}\eta^{\mu\nu}.$$
This leads to the appearance of (Pauli-Villars) ghosts in the Hilbert, e.g. the state
$$\left|\psi\right> = \alpha_m^0\left|0\right>\qquad\qquad\left<\psi\middle|\psi\right> = -m <0.$$
These negative-norm states make the theory sick in arbitrary dimensions, and the no-ghost theorem states that in $d=26$, physical states (those that are Virasoro primaries of weight 1) do not have negative norm (roughly, one can be more precise but this is not relevant here).
I understand that the critical dimension goes beyond this simple argument, and in the path integral formulation, I need to gauge fix and introduce Faddeev-Popov/BRST ghost to obtain a unitary non-anomalous theory, which can be done only in $d=26$.
I however fail to see why the presence of Pauli-Villars ghosts is an inherently string-theoretic result. In the argument above, the origin of the non-negative norm can be traced back to the fact that $\eta^{00}=-1$, not that the worldsheet metric is dynamical. If I did not care about string theory and was just a 2d conformal field theorist interested in free bosons rotated by an $\mathfrak{so}(a,b)$ symmetry without a 2d gravitational background, shouldn't I find a similar result that only comes from the fact that I have imposed a global symmetry with a Lorentzian signature? On the other hand, the $O(N)$ free compact boson is a perfectly fine unitary theory.
It naively seems that people are merging two types of concepts of (albeit related) ghosts, namely Pauli-Villars ghosts defined as non-negative norm space on the Fock space, and Faddeev-Popov ghosts associated with gauge fixing in the path integral formalism. Are the Pauli-Villars ones really string related?

Hi Bulkilol. Are you following a reference? Which pages?

I don't follow a reference in particular, but it's e.g. in Green-Schwarz-Witten I, chapter 2. The relevant section is 2.2. They do mention the Weyl anomaly, but I don't see the relation between Pauli-Vilars ghost and the Weyl anomaly, since the ghosts are there even if the worldsheet metric is non-dynamical.

In a footnote in page 76 of my edition ("Commutation Relations and Mode Expansions"),  they mention that the ghosts I'm (and they are) talking about are not to be confused with BRST ghosts. I think I came up on "Pauli-Villars ghosts" by reading up on the no-ghost theorem. I can't remember the exact place that introduced that name. The point is that sticking to canonical quantisation, I do not see where the usual issue of gauge fixing arises. I would argue that negative-norm states will be there for any flat QFT of free 2d bosons if there is a non-unitary flavor/global symmetry like so(1,d-1).

TL;DR: No, OP is right: Negative-norm ghost states are not string related per se; they appear in other theories as well, typically in gauge theories, e.g. in the extended Hilbert space for Yang-Mills theory.

Thanks! But here, they do not arise from gauge fixing, right? They'll also appear for free compact bosons, which is a CFT that does not have a gauge symmetry (i.e. they don't per se appear from partially gauging the diff x Weyl symmetry.)
